# FlakyTest test not working to run same test again and again for instrumentation.

Tags: android, android-instrumentation

I want to run my test case again and again for number of times as my parameter changes but the scenarios are the same for that 
I have tried with **Flaky Test** but it is not working.

While exploring also come to know it is deprecated.
here is the [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/FlakyTest.html)

```
 @FlakyTest(tolerance = 3)
    public void myTest() {
        // Test that sometimes fails for no good reason
    }
```

Above code is not working for me and it is running only once.
I am not finding any way how to run same test case again and again.